# To what does the width em refer if there is no parent container with width?

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML/CSS, right now im struggling through a tutorial and I'm wondering to what does that em `width: 2em` from `#menubar ul` refer to?

In the parent containers, there is no width to which it could refer? Or maybe I get something wrong here.

```html
    <body>

    <section id="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menubutton" href="#menu"> <img src="images/menu.png"> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <header>
        <h1>HMTLworldBLOG</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="main">
        <article>
            <h2>Das ist ein Artikel</h2>
            <img src="images/bild.jpg">
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </article>

        <aside>
            <section>
                <h2>Weitere Artikel</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Noch einer</li>
                    <li>Noch einer</li>
                    <li>Noch einer</li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>Ein Textfeld</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h2>Kategorien</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>HTML</li>
                    <li>CSS</li>
                    <li>PHP</li>
                    <li>jquery</li>
                    <li>Tool</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </aside>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li>Kontakt</li>
            <li>Datenschutz</li>
            <li>Impressum</li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```css
body {
background: #DCDCDC;
font-size: 100%;          
margin: 0em;              
padding: 0em;            
}

h1 {
font-size: 2.5em;
line-height: 3.8em;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
color: #E2DBDB;
margin: 0em;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.563em;
line-height: 1.8em;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
color: #2F2D2C;
margin: 0em;
padding: 1.25em;
text-align: left;
}

p {                        
line-height: 1.25em;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
color: #2F2D2C;
margin: 0em;
padding: 1.25em;           
text-align: justify;        
}

ul {
margin: 0px;               
padding: 0px;               
}

li {
list-style: square;
line-height: 1.25em;
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
color: #2F2D2C;
margin: 0.313em 0em 0.313em 0em;
padding: 1.25em;
}

img {                          
width: 90%;                 
height: auto;               
max-width: 100%;            
}

a {                           
text-decoration: none;
}


/*******ON TOP BAR******/

#menubar {
display: block;            
background: #ffffff;
}

#menubar ul {                   
display: block;            
width: 2em;              
padding: 0.9em;             
}

#menubar ul li {            
display: inline;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `em` unit of measurement is calculated relative to the `font-size` of an element which, if not explicitly defined, is (usually) inherited from its parent element. With a `font-size` of `16px`, `1em` would be equal to 16 pixels. If a `font-size` is defined using an `em` unit then it will be relative to its inherited `font-size` (i.e., the parent element's `font-size`).

In your specific example, the `width` of `2em` would be twice the `font-size` of the `#menubar ul` element, which would be inherited from the body's `font-size` which is set to `100%`.

**[Further reading on <length> units from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)**

Answer (score 0):

let me explain this in the simplest possible way.

**EM** is a relative unit. It always works based on it's parent element's font-size.

1. In the below snippet, try changing the h1 tag's em into something
   bigger.
2. Now, change it's parent tag ".em-tutorial"'s base font size into
   something smaller.

**Did your heading's font size also become smaller?**

That's because em's are calculated with respect to the parent element (.em-tutorial, in this case).

```css
.em-tutorial {
  font-size:10px;
}

.em-tutorial h1 {
  font-size:5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="em-tutorial">
<h1>This heading has a font size of 2em</h1>
</div>
            
<div class="em-tutorial">
<h1>This heading has a font size of 2em</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

'em' is a unit for expressing a length in css.

Please read the link

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: This is no different from a link-only answer. The non-link part is stating the obvious and does not actually address the question.